# How do I make a section of my react app only accessible to those who have subscribed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the title says,

I’m wanting to develop a react app where a certain section of the program is only accessible to those who have purchased a subscription. But I’m unsure about the step by step process required.

I’m quite new to react, but if any of you have any guidance to my dilemma it would be much appreciated <3,

Comment: Checkout https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web which is a library for protected  routes. Maybe not exactly your situation? What does subscription mean? It websocket/channel? A paid service?

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more clarification. I don't know how you plan to make the subscription.

Regardless, the easiest way to hide a component from specific group of viewers is by creating a private component.

Typically, a private component it used to protect routes that need authorization — something like a Dashboard where a user has to sign in.

In your case, I don't know what you plan to use, but most of the time a token, or something like that Is used.

I will be using a Boolean to authenticate (which is not ideal).

So after  a user has purchased a subscription, you can create a constant like hasPurchased and set it to true and advisably, should be saved in an app-level state.

Then you should create a protected route like so

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest, hasPurchased  }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => (!hasPurchased? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Component {...props} />)}
  />
)

export default PrivateRoute
```

So basically, what this component will do is to check if the user has purchased via the hasPurchased props that is been passed down. If that's true it will render the component your passed and if is the other way around, it will redirect to the homepage.

Note: you will need react-router-dom to do this.

Comment: Wow. You provided so much clarity for me. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Cheers mate! If this answer works for you, upvote it and Mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case in my app where only admins can see few components. We had a PermissionWrapper component which shows/hides/disables or limits few actions based on the permissions and other props. You can have a SubscriptionWrapper similarly.

Your SubscriptionWrapper component can look like this:

```
const SubscriptionWrapper = ({
  hasSubscribed
}) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {hasSubscribed
        ? children
        null
          })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Your components which should be only visible to subscribed users should be wrapped with the subscriptionWrapper like so:

```
<SubscriptionWrapper hasSubscribed={hasSubscribed}>
     <SpecialComponent/>
</SubscriptionWrapper>
```

The reason for having a whole new component instead of having a simple check is that you can extend this wrapper Component for other actions like disabling or limiting events on your components and not just hiding. Also, store your *hasSubscribed* value globally (App level or in Redux).